# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Char[]' to 'System.byte[]' with HMACSHA1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity project with this simple piece of code in C#:

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();       
byte[] keyBytes = encoding.GetBytes(Manager.Instance.Configuration.ClientSecretKey);
HMACSHA1 hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(keyBytes);
```

It works fine on every platforms: Unity Editor, Android, iPhone, ...
But not on Windows Phone! Here is below a screenshot of the exception.

[image]

I don't understand why it happens as keyBytes is obviously a byte[] object...

Comment: From the looks of it, must be a bug in runtime on Windows Phone.. (something inside `HMAC.InitializeKey` method or the CLR). Sounds improbable, but only possibility which comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How the heck are you using `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding`?

Try `System.Text.UTF8Encoding` instead.

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
```

---

[MSDN Forum Regarding `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding`](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/8a844a21-39cf-4134-8010-53bea1080852/systemtextasciiencoding-missing?forum=winappswithcsharp)

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try. Does the result will be the same as with ASCII encoding?

Comment: @ZouBi as Wes Haggard (MSFT) said on the forum post, it should be compatible.

Comment: Thank you. I can't test until tomorrow, so I will get back to you later to let you know if it worked and marker your reply as answer.